# SUM of filled AWS Cloudwatch metric not correct

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

A CloudWatch metric I previously used (mOld) was replaced by a new metric (mNew).

I am now trying to build the sum over the old metric until the day we switched and the new metric after that day. The old metric is still being used, but differently, therefore I cannot just build the sum of both metrics.

I have tried it this way:

This is roughly what my source looks like:

```
[ "...", { "id": "mOld"} ],
[ "...", { "id": "mNew"} ],
[ { "expression": "FILL(mNew, mOld)", "id": "filledMetric" }],
[ { "expression": "SUM(filledMetric)", "id": "filledSum" }]
```

I am filling the new metric with the values of the old metric and then calculate the sum of that expression.
Plotting the "filledMetric" on a line chart looks exactly like I would expect. The time frame before "mNew" was active is filled by the values of mOld.

But when I then take the sum of "filledMetric", it only includes the values of "mNew", not "mOld". The sum does not increase when the timeframe starts before the day I switched metrics.

I'd like to understand why this is the case. Is there any other way to calculate the sum of mOld until day x and mNew after day x?